# Reading Python CDispatch object only gives the first line

Tags: python, recordset

first question coming up...have just started using Python 3.6. I am creating an XML format document of tabulated data. The document object itself has a collection called CellValues. Using Dimensions (aka Unicom Intelligence) I can read this collection as a record set and loop round it with .movenext() etc.
However when I read it in Python with:

```
rs=tomdoc.tables["T0"].cellvalues()
for val in rs:
    print(val)
```

I only see the first line. In contrast, when I connect to a SqL database, the returned object is a SQLrows type and prints the whole thing, but this one says it's CDispatch.
How can I get it to either loop round or show me the whole recordset?
Apologies for my ignorance and thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please let me know of any further information that would help.

Comment: were you able to solve this? I'm wondering whether there may be some default property value for the `val` object or the `rs` object. You could try explicitly `for val in rs.Fields` maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a colleague, I do now have a working process.
In fact the collection needs to be indexed this way:

```
rs = tomdoc.Tables("T0").CellValues
```

Then it can be read as one normally would read a SQL-type record set:

```
rs.MoveFirst()
while not rs.EOF:
    rowStr = ""
    for f in rs.Fields:
        rowStr += f.value + "\t"
    print(rowStr)
    rs.MoveNext()
```

I'm not sure why the ["T0"] gave me the first line though - that threw me somewhat and made it look closer than it actually was (one of those jolly things one encounters when mixing objects) so I didn't investigate alternatives for that part of the script :(